# Tracking change in audit table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a audit table as follows:

```
empid|division id|dept id|lastupdated
1|      A|             20|xxxxx
3|      C|             10|xxxxxx
6|      D|             10|xxxxxx
1|      D|             10|xxxxxx
1|      B|             10|xxxxxx
3|      E|             10|xxxxxx
```

I need to filter out records with dept id=10,which has been updated in the last 2 days.
However,the record should be selected ONLY if the previous entry for the same emp had a different dept.

i.e. find out all records updated over the last 2 days where the dept has 'changed' to 10(from something else)in the last update.
Note that the last update to that person may have been much earlier than the 2-day window.
So expected output above -

```
1|      D|             10|xxxxxx
```

Can this be done without resorting to temp tables?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tableName t1
INNER JOIN tableName t2
ON t1.emp_id=t2.emp_id and t1.dept_id<>t2.dept_id
WHERE datediff(day,t1.lastudated,GETDATE())<=2 AND t1.lastupdated > t2.lastupdated
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d6e3d/3)

Comment: This will keep selecting the record if there has been any change in its dept any time in history.I need the record to be selected only once - only on change of deptid and not thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select t1.* from tablename as t1 inner join
(
    select emp_id from tablename
    where lastudated>=dateadd(day,-2,lastudated)
    group by emp_id
    having min(dep_id)<>max(dept_id) and min(dept_id)=10
) as t2 on t1.emp_id=t2.emp_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select t1.* from tablename as t1 
cross apply(
                select t2.emp_id from tablename as t2
                where DATEDIFF(dd,t2.lastudated,dateadd(day,-2,GETDATE())) = 0
                and t2.emp_id = t1.emp_id
                and t1.dept_id <> t2.dept_id
            ) as t3
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing this should get you there or close to where you are trying to get.

```
SELECT t1.empid ,
       t1.divisionid ,
       t1.deptid ,
       t1.lastupdated 
FROM  YourTable t1
INNER JOIN YourTable t2 ON t1.empid=t2.empid and t1.deptid<>t2.deptid and t1.lastupdated>t2.lastupdated
WHERE t1.lastupdated BETWEEN DateAdd(day, -3, GetDate()) AND DateAdd(day, 1, GetDate())
     AND t2.lastupdated BETWEEN DateAdd(day, -3, GetDate()) AND DateAdd(day, 1, GetDate())
```