# For each operation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a audit table(AUDIT) as follows:

```
empid|division id|dept id|lastupdated
1|      A|             20|xxxxx
3|      C|             10|xxxxxx
6|      D|             10|xxxxxx
1|      D|             10|xxxxxx
1|      B|             10|xxxxxx
3|      E|             10|xxxxxx
```

For each row in this table ,I want to compare data with the immediately previous record (based on lastupdated date).
The result should filter records wherein deptid are not equal on comparison between the 2 records.

```
Pseudocode:

For each record in AUDIT t1
1.Select dept id,max(lastupdated) from AUDIT t2 where t1.lastupdated > t2.lastupdated
2.Select t1.empid if t1.deptid<> t2.deptid(from step 1)
```

Is this possible as a single sql query - rather than temp table operations?

Comment: Which version of SQL SERVER are you using?

Comment: Is it a duplicate of your own question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22809305/tracking-change-in-audit-table

Answer (score 0):

```
select  * from AUDIT a  inner join AUDIT b 
on a.empid = b.empid and a.[division id] = b.[division id] 
and  b.lastupdated =(select max(lastupdated) from AUDIT c where lastupdated < a.lastupdated) where a.deptid <> b.deptid
```